# is there any way for coloring register in pyqt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyserial

[image]

I am generating this GUI for BMS system by pyqt5, python, and pyserial and I've used in QT designer to make this.

I'm trying to code this gui working like colored qlabel by register value. Such like if I get System Status(0x00) value with HEX is A7 which means Binary is 10100111. Then I wanna color my register value such like CCRDY, DEV_XD, OV,SCD and OCD but I just come up with one idea with just only hard coding by using if statement and just if value is 1 then write such like this.

self.charge_status.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)')

Is there any way to make it easier? I just only use Qlabel for that register name.

Comment: @ilyasbbu that is not an image of the code, it's a screenshot of the GUI, so it's completely fine to show it.

Comment: Can you try to improve your explanation with clear examples? Right now what you referred to is quite unintelligible to us, and it would help to have practical examples of the wanted results.